# Getting the Facebook Access Token OUTSIDE of the function

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

So I am using a function as such to get the access token of the already authenticated user that is currently on my website:

```
var token;
FB.getLoginStatus(
        function(response){
            if (response.session) { 
                alert(response.session.access_token);
                //This correctly shows the access token. <-----GOOD 
                token = response.session.access_token;
            } 
            else{
                //Other stuff.  
            }
        }
);
alert(token);
//This shows undefined.  <------PROBLEM
```

The only way to know the access token it seems is to be within the anonymous function called within the call to FB.getLoginStatus.

I have determined that the problem is that the anonymous function inside of FB.getLoginStatus is not executed until the end of all other scripts on the page.  Therefore, the variable "token" will not be set until everything is done executing, rendering it useless.

Is there a way then to extract the access token into a universally accessible variable?  I don't want to have to write all my code which requires knowledge of the access token in a single anonymous function.

Comment: Try `window.token = response.session.access_token;`...

Comment: Still no dice as the setting of the variable pretty much is the last thing to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the expression `FB._session.access_token` to get the access token from any other location.

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I was only initially using the call to FB.getLoginStatus because I did not know of any other way to get the access token.  Nowhere in the FB documentation could I find such a variable as the one you gave me (awful documentation)....where did you find this?

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Lots of pain and suffering and searching through Google to find that one.

Answer (score 2):

Ye the issue is that the getLoginStatus is an asynchronous call that connects to the FB api. But in the meanwhile your script continues running and so the alert(token); gets called before the getLoginStatus() finished. So the token is not set yet.

I don't know what you want to do exactly with the token, but my way to do this would be to call a function inside the getLoginStatus() as soon as the token has been loaded, and then proceed with the functionality you want. So...

```
var token;
FB.getLoginStatus(
        function(response){
            if (response.session) { 
                alert(response.session.access_token);
                //This correctly shows the access token. <-----GOOD 
                token = response.session.access_token;
                continueScript();
            } 
            else{
                //Other stuff.  
            }
        }
);


function continueScript() {
      ....
      doSomeMoreFunctionalitiesWithToken();
      ....
}

function doSomeMoreFunctionalitiesWithToken() {
      alert(token);
}
```

You could for example just show a "loading..." indicator on the screen and only remove it and show the actual content **after** the getLoginStatus() finished its task and thus **after** the token has been set.

Hope this helps you.